# Limit lattice plots to viewports?

Tags: r, plot, viewport, lattice, r-grid

I would like to fit a whole lattice plot in a small region of an existing plot.

```
xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos, type = "a")
pushViewport(viewport(.2, .7, .2, .2))
grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="white"))
```

gives me this:

[image]

So viewport is pushed. But when if a lattice function is called again, it uses the whole device, as if calling `grid.newpage()`:

```
xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos, type = "a")
```

Is there a way to limit lattice plots to a predefined region on a device like in my example above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to directly call `print` with `newpage` argument set to `FALSE` (opposite to default value):

```
xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos, type = "a")
pushViewport(viewport(.2, .7, .2, .2))
print(xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos, type = "a"), newpage=FALSE)
```

You could find it in grid manual (r_instalation_path/library/grid/doc/grid.pdf), section "Adding lattice to grid".

[image]